# Generating complete (java/java-script) clients to restfull service

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-rs

I hope that my question want repeat any other similar questions.
I am kind of new in the web services area, and in particular in the restfull area.
I have a jboss server, and I have written a java web service using resteasy implementation to jax-rs.
I would like to generate a :

1. Java client
2. Java script client

I would like those clients to be a working client (and not stubs – interfaces). In other words I would like an automated way of reflecting the server into a client. And I want that client to work without any additional code.

If this request is applicable (I hope that I did not ask for the moon here), I wondering if there is a way that this client generation will occur automatically (by running some kind of make command [ maven?])?

I tried of using the wadl2java tool, but I am not sure if this is right for me, because it is a glassfish product.

I would like to point out that my service is documented by a wadl doc, and I am wondering if this is the most “right” way to document a rest service.

Comment: If you want a client to execute your REST service, Chrome/Firefox browsers has a plugin called REST Client, you google it and download, install. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to test you rest ws manually, you can use [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) from Chrome;

if you want automated tests you can use the rest client from the jersey implementation of jax-rs client

```
protected final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.target(URL).request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE).get();
```

pom dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you
My question is, if one of my methods return a type, let’s say “costumer type”, how to I use your code in order to get an object costumer type on the client side from the service?
I mean, do I have a way of doing:
Costumer_type ct = client.target(URL).request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE).get();

Comment: javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = client.target(URL).request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE).get();

and response, now, contains the web service response :)

Comment: ok. but how can i convert form response object in to  Costumer_type?

Comment: let me bug you some more. what if i want to my Customer class can make some operations against the server, lets say create, view , and delete. and lately i have added the delete operation. is there a way for me to  Automatically generate the Customer class on the client side? lats assume they are Separated